# python selenium - change cell value in Excel Online table

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to edit a cell's value using Selenium for Python in an Online Excel table?

I would like to simulate the act of a user clicking a cell and typing into it.

I can read the data that exists in the table, but do not know how to edit 
a cell's contents. Reading the values can be done like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome('path_to_driver')
driver.get('my_Online_Excel_sheet')
driver.switch_to.frame('WebApplicationFrame')

# return the text in the cell
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gridRows"]/div[3]/div[3]/div').text
```

I then naturally tried Selenium's `send_keys` method, but it does not work on these types of elements as far as I can tell.

I also tried to use `execute_script`, which seems really promising, runs without error, but does not actually appear to change the value in the cell.

```py
cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gridRows"]/div[3]/div[3]/div')
cell.click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'some_new_value';", cell)
```

Here is the HTML element that corresponds to the cell in the table (the current value is 101):

```html
<div class="cv-nwr ewr-vab" style="width: 61px; max-heith: 19px; text-align: right;">101</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements cannot take input.  I doubt the cells are divs.  They would have to be `<input>` elements of some kind.  Have you tried inspecting the element with the browser developer tools?

Comment: Please share the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit]

Comment: @JohnGordon I have inspected the element. I have added some other details that may clarify that.

Comment: @QHarr Please see edits. I also tried the method `execute_script` which seems promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I can change the cell's value by altering the inner HTML using:

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'new_text';", cell)
```

Unfortunately, the change doesn't hold once the page is refreshed, but perhaps there is a way to programatically save the sheet, or some other way of getting the new value to stick.